# Name decoration or name mangling in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, cygwin, name-mangling

I have generated dll file using cygwin and I am trying to use it in Visual Studio.

1. I got the DEF(.def) file with mangled function names as part of cygwin compilation.
2. Using lib.exe program which comes as part of MSVC, I generated .lib file.

In MSVC, I wrote a program which used the function from the lib file which was created.

I got Linker errors.
When I checked the mangled names,the one in DEF file is different to the one in the error thrown in MSVC.
I demangled both and found that MSVC has mangled the function name with `__cdecl` keyword.

How can I create mangled function names in cygwin with `__cdecl` keyword? Am I missing any flags in cgwin compilation?

Visual Studio:
Mangled name:

> (__imp_?configure_tls_context@client@asio_http2@nghttp2@@YA?AVerror_code@system@boost@@AAV456@AAVcontext@ssl@asio@6@@Z)

Demangled name:

> (__imp_class boost::system::error_code __cdecl
>   nghttp2::asio_http2::client::configure_tls_context(class
>   boost::system::error_code &,class boost::asio::ssl::context &)

DEF file from Cygwin:
Mangled name:

> _ZN7nghttp210asio_http26client21configure_tls_contextERN5boost6system10error_codeERNS2_4asio3ssl7contextE

Demangled name:

> nghttp2::asio_http2::client::configure_tls_context(boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::ssl::context&)

Comment: It's not just the name mangling you have to deal with, but potentially also the calling convention, and other issues, such as POSIX compatibility. Why not simply recompile the library with VC++? Or simply compile everything with Cygwin GCC.

Comment: I followed the steps from this link https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.msvcrt-and-cygwin . Based on the solution provided in that link, I thought dll generated in cygwin could be used in MSVC and I am missing some compiler flags in Cygwin due to which I am facing linker errors. Recompiling the library with VC++ is my last resort.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule; with C++ code you always need to compile *all* code for your project with *the exact same compiler*. This includes the executable and all static and dynamic libraries. C++ does not have a ABI specification and all compilers may mangle names differently and even new minor versions of a compiler may produce code that is incompatible with code built with previous versions.
There is no standard for name mangling or data structure layout etc.

So; always recompile *all* source code with the *exact same* compiler or be prepared for a world of pain.

Comment: I too thought the same "compilers may mangle names differently".  I followed this link [link](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.msvcrt-and-cygwin) for the usage of cygwin generated dll in MSVC. Maybe the provided solution is only for C and not C++.